# Using three.js One of my geometry shapes starts to flicker when i attempt to render another shape

Tags: three.js

I am fairly new to three.js and was playing around with some tutorial and examples, to attempt to build a basic human figure. Everything was working fine as I was modifying code from a tutorial. However when I 6th shape, the roundedRect shape started to flicker, and i have no idea why. I have had a look online and couldnt find anything that helped. I get this problem in chrome and not firefox - both latest versions

My code is as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/Three.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/stats.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script>
    var container, stats;

var camera, scene, renderer;

var text, plane;

var targetRotation = 0;
var targetRotationOnMouseDown = 0;

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;

var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );



    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.set( 0, 200, 500 );
    scene.add( camera );

    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
    light.position.set( 0, 0, 1 );
    scene.add( light );

    parent = new THREE.Object3D();
    parent.position.y = 50;
    scene.add( parent );

    function addGeometry( geometry, points, spacedPoints, color, x, y, z, rx, ry, rz, s ) {

        // 3d shape

        var mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( geometry, [ new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: color } ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00FF00, wireframe: false, transparent: false } ) ] );
        mesh.position.set( x, y, z );
        mesh.rotation.set( rx, ry, rz );
        mesh.scale.set( s, s, s );
        parent.add( mesh );
    }

    var extrudeSettings = { amount: 20,  bevelEnabled: true, bevelSegments: 2, steps: 2 }; // bevelSegments: 2, steps: 2 , bevelSegments: 5, bevelSize: 8, bevelThickness:5,

    //head 

    var headShape = new THREE.Shape();
    headBuild(headShape,-40, 150, 30, 50, 20);

    var head3d = headShape.extrude( extrudeSettings );
    var headPoints = headShape.createPointsGeometry();
    var headSpacedPoints = headShape.createSpacedPointsGeometry();

    function headBuild(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius)
    {
        ctx.moveTo( x, y + radius );
        ctx.lineTo( x, y + height - radius );
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x, y + height, x + radius, y + height );
        ctx.lineTo( x + width - radius, y + height) ;
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x + width, y + height, x + width, y + height - radius );
        ctx.lineTo( x + width, y + radius );
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x + width, y, x + width - radius, y );
        ctx.lineTo( x + radius, y );
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x, y, x, y + radius );
    }


    // Body

    var roundedRectShape = new THREE.Shape();
    roundedRect( roundedRectShape, -40, 150, 50, 100, 20 );

    var roundedRect3d = roundedRectShape.extrude( extrudeSettings );
    var roundedRectPoints = roundedRectShape.createPointsGeometry();
    var roundedRectSpacedPoints = roundedRectShape.createSpacedPointsGeometry();

    function roundedRect( ctx, x, y, width, height, radius ){

        ctx.moveTo( x, y + radius );
        ctx.lineTo( x, y + height - radius );
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x, y + height, x + radius, y + height );
        ctx.lineTo( x + width - radius, y + height) ;
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x + width, y + height, x + width, y + height - radius );
        ctx.lineTo( x + width, y + radius );
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x + width, y, x + width - radius, y );
        ctx.lineTo( x + radius, y );
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x, y, x, y + radius );

    }



    //Legs

    var longSide = 100;
    var shortSide = 40;

    var legsShape = new THREE.Shape();


    legsShape.moveTo(0,100);
    legsShape.lineTo(40,100);
    legsShape.lineTo(60,-40);
    legsShape.lineTo(40,-40);
    legsShape.lineTo(20,80);
    legsShape.lineTo(0,-40);
    legsShape.lineTo(-20,-40);
    legsShape.lineTo(0,100);



    var legs3d = legsShape.extrude( extrudeSettings );
    var legsPoints = legsShape.createPointsGeometry();
    var legsSpacedPoints = legsShape.createSpacedPointsGeometry();

    //Left Arm

    var leftArmShape = new THREE.Shape();
    leftArmShape.moveTo(0,100);
    leftArmShape.lineTo(10,100);
    leftArmShape.lineTo(-20,0);
    leftArmShape.lineTo(-30,0);
    leftArmShape.lineTo(0,100);


    var leftArm3d = leftArmShape.extrude( extrudeSettings );
    var leftArmPoints = leftArmShape.createPointsGeometry();
    var leftArmSpacedPoints = leftArmShape.createSpacedPointsGeometry();

    //Right Arm

    var rightArmShape = new THREE.Shape();
    rightArmShape.moveTo(0,100);
    rightArmShape.lineTo(10,100);
    rightArmShape.lineTo(30,0);
    rightArmShape.lineTo(20,0);
    rightArmShape.lineTo(0,100);


    var rightArm3d = rightArmShape.extrude( extrudeSettings );
    var rightArmPoints = rightArmShape.createPointsGeometry();
    var rightArmSpacedPoints = rightArmShape.createSpacedPointsGeometry();

    //extra 

    var extraShape = new THREE.Shape();
    extraShape.moveTo(0,100);
    extraShape.lineTo(10,100);
    extraShape.lineTo(30,0);
    extraShape.lineTo(20,0);
    extraShape.lineTo(0,100);

    var extra3d = extraShape.extrude(extrudeSettings);
    var extraPoints = extraShape.createPointsGeometry();
    var extraSpacedPoints = extraShape.createSpacedPointsGeometry();

    //After colour / pos x,y,z rot, x,y,z
    addGeometry( roundedRect3d, roundedRectPoints, roundedRectSpacedPoints, 0x005500, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 );
    addGeometry( head3d, headPoints, headSpacedPoints,  0x005500, 20, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 );
    addGeometry( legs3d, legsPoints, legsSpacedPoints,  0x005500, -25, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 );
    addGeometry( leftArm3d, leftArmPoints, leftArmSpacedPoints, 0x005500, -40, 145, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 );
    addGeometry( rightArm3d, rightArmPoints, rightArmSpacedPoints,  0x005500, 20, 145, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 );
    addGeometry( extra3d, extraPoints, extraSpacedPoints,   0x005500, 200, 145, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 );
    //addGeometry( throat3d, throatPoints, throatSpacedPoints,  0x005500, 20, 145, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 );
    //

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    stats = new Stats();
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
            container.appendChild( stats.domElement );


    document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );

}

//

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

    mouseXOnMouseDown = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
    targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;

}

function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

    mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;

    targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown + ( mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown ) * 0.02;

}

function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {

    document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
    document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
    document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

}

function onDocumentMouseOut( event ) {

    document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
    document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
    document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

}

function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {

    if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {

        event.preventDefault();

        mouseXOnMouseDown = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
        targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;

    }

}

function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {

    if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {

        event.preventDefault();

        mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
        targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown + ( mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown ) * 0.05;

    }

}

//

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();
    stats.update();

}

function render() {

    parent.rotation.y += ( targetRotation - parent.rotation.y ) * 0.05;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: In `THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject` try to remove the `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial` parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I changed
var mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( geometry, [ new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: color } ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00FF00, wireframe: true, transparent: true } ) ] ); 

to 

var mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( geometry, [ new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: color } )]);

and seems to work fine. Thanks @JuanMellado